# add custom image field for custom options in magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce, magento-1.8

I am working on magento 1.9 version.I want to add a custom image field in drop down of custom options.
I added a text field using following guide

http://magento.ikantam.com/qa/how-add-custom-attributes-custom-options

which is working fine.but when I add a file field then it shows in admin but not save image field value in database.

[image]

please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Neeraj,

Did you specifically click "flush cache storage"  By following this guide and adding new tables directly to the database, Magento already has this record in cache.  By flushing cache storage, you will allow magento to recognize the new structure and be able to save the record.  I have accidentally forgotten to do this quite a few times and you end up with the inability to save a record even though your structure is there.